# Суть метода @classmethod, @staticmethod, @property

Tags: python, классы, методы

Подскажите пожалуйтса, конкретно для каких ситуаций эти методы предназначены?. Потому что код, где они используются, можно же выполнять и без них. Например:

```
 class Gamers:
        count = 0
        
        @classmethod
        def show_gamers(cls):
            return cls.count
```

выполнение же не изменится если убрать метод:

```
class Gamers:
    count = 0
    
    def show_gamers():
        return Gamers.count
```

Точно так же и с @staticmethod, @property ...

Comment: вообще вопрос включает несколько вопросов если интересует детальные объяснения для каждого метода. В общем необходимо прочитать про декораторы.

Answer (score 0):

А это потому что вы не используете параметр `cls`, а вот если бы использовали, то и вопроса бы не было:

```
 class Gamers:
        count = 0
        
        @classmethod
        def show_gamers(cls):
            return cls.count 
                   ^^^ универсальный указатель на класс
```

Теперь можно наследоваться от этого класса и спокойно использовать этот метод, не переписывая его, он будет работать с любым классом, а не только с жёстко вами прописанным. Ну, если такова задумка, конечно.

Comment: опять таки , без использования @classmetod при наследовании, всервано потомок унаследует же метод,  без переписывния метода...

Comment: можно какой-то кокретный пример привести... смотрел видео , читаль статьи, толком не понял конкретное их назначение...